# Problems getting psycopg2 installed for PostgreSQL, Django

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2

-Mac OSX 10.7.5
-Python 2.7 
-PostgreSQL 9.3.2 (set up via Heroku)
-Django 1.6

I've spent the entire day trying to solve this problem and have not been able to find a solution. I'm trying to get my Django app to recognize a Postgres database. The database setting in my django settings.py is

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
}
```

}

The first thing I did to get psycopg2 installed was download Macports, which was successful.Then in the terminal I typed

sudo port install py27-psycopg2

I didn't get any error messages, so assumed the install was successful.

Just to check I fired up the python shell and did:

```
>>import psycopg2
```

That produced the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named psycopg2
```

I retyped "sudo port install py27-psycopg2" but got this:

```
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 file2
   install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
           [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
   install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
```

Does anybody know what might be going on here? I did read that Macports installs a different version of python and I'm wondering if perhaps my current version of python isn't recognizing psycopg2. If so, how do I activate the Macports version and would it recognize my django app?

Comment: macports installed it on the macports version of Python, not the system Python.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I will need to do "sudo port install python27".  Is there anything after "sudo port install python27" that I need to do get Macports python working with django, Git and other programs my current python is working with? I know it's kind of vague, but I don't fully know all the things Macports is changing when it loads the new version of python. thnx.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtualenv to load your django environment. The advantage to doing this is you can be 100% certain that the modules you need and the interpreter aren't being confused between the system and the ports versions. I use macports as well and from ports only install python27, py27-pip, and py27-virtualenv. From there, all other modules I install are within a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Mac OS X, however, I strongly suggest that the best practice is to build your working python environment using virtualenv.

Instead of using any package manager to install the desired packages system-wide, it is easier (more portable, more flexible, etc) to use **pip** and install only the necessary python packages for the specific project you are working on.

Here is a very [insightful post](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/18/starting-a-django-16-project-the-right-way/) on how to properly setup a django environment.

[This post](https://gist.github.com/pithyless/1208841) gives a list of commands to install Python 2.7 homebrew + pip + virtualenv on Mac OS X Lion, for example. (Just a google result. I have never tried it)

I hope this will become a good start for less headaches in the future!